# Property [x] does not exist on this collection instance using with() with polymorphic

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

I get this error `Property [status] does not exist on this collection instance` when I am trying to get the value of the column, here is my code

```
$lab = Lab::select('id', 'services_cat_id', 'resp_doctor_id', 'invoice_id', 'xray_file', 'status', 'note')->where('patient_id', '3')
        ->with(['invoice' => function ($q) {
            $q->select('invoiceable_id','id', 'code', 'status');}])
        ->orderBy('status', 'ASC')
        ->get();
```

in blade:

```
@foreach ($lab as $item)

{{$item->invoice->status}}
```

Comment: Does the error message actually say "Property [x]"?

Comment: it says Property [status] does not exist on this collection instance

Comment: Would you mind sharing the migration, model class? What does it say when you dump `$item` out to the view?

Comment: Are you meant to be able to have multiple invoices for a `Lab`?